# How to get the path of a Data Package in Service Fabric?

Tags: c#, deployment, azure-service-fabric

I created a Data Package under the PackageRoot of my SF service (called `WebSvc`) which contains a License.xml file, like so:

> ApplicationTypePackageRoot
>   --> WebSvcPkg
>       --> Data
>           --> License.xml

Now in my C# code, I would like to get the full path to the License.xml file.  How to do this?

Comment: How do you get this path for a guest executable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like you can find the path via the `CodePackageActivationContext` of the service:

```
 var dataPackage = this.serviceContext.CodePackageActivationContext.GetDataPackageObject("Data");
 var nsbLicensePath = Path.Combine(dataPackage.Path, "License.xml");
```

Comment: Yup, that's the way to do it.